# How to set "current_user" in Meteor

Tags: meteor, account, createuser

When I develop a Meteor app, I can get user's information from third party(not oauth), so how to set current_user variable without Accounts.loginWithPassword or Accounts.loginWith[Service] methods?

Accounts.createUser only return a userid,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is even possible as something like this would let anyone with someone's userId log in to their account without their password.

Comment: This is not worry,  the app will get information form third party.

Comment: One thing you could try is `this.setUserId(userId)`
This will associate the current connection with the user. It affects the current method call and any future method calls on the connection.
But this will not log the user in on the client side.